# Bitmap Resource Scaling Android

Tags: android, bitmap

So I'm running some tests to see how bitmaps I've loaded are displayed on different density screens.

I'm running tests on my personal phone (Galaxy S4) which is a xxhdpi phone. I have a drawable bitmap resource that is 315px * 315px in the xxhdpi folder. I scaled this image down and placed versions in each of the following folders (All units in pixels):

```
xhdpi = 210 x 210
hdpi = 157.5 x 157.5
mdpi = 105 x 105
ldpi = 78.75 x 78.75
```

This bitmap displays in a proper proportion when viewed on my S4 but when I load this in the emulator with a mdpi device it appears much smaller than it should.

I went by the scaling guidelines on the android developers site so I figured scaling the images down accordingly takes the DP into account. I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference page with pixels: http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Here is the Google reference page: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I do not know the specifics of your app, but I will note two things which could be the problem:

1) These **pixel sizes are *estimates*** they are not guaranteed. Real phones come in all shapes and sizes with different screen resolutions so it is hard to make a truly res independent UI. and just these different sizes will not help. Therefore your phone might be a tad different from your emulator.

2) The scaling needs to be (3:)4:6:8:12:16. ((ldpi:)mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi:xxxhdpi) (for example: 32:48:72:96:180:192. e.g. for a 48x48 baseline (.75x:)1x:1.5x:2x:3x:4x) so scale accordingly for it to mostly work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm a little bit confused. So the scaling is 3:4:6:8:12:16. How does the 180 values make sense there? If the scaling for those two is 3x the 1x value, wouldnt it be 48 x 3 (144) where the 180 is? Something just seems odd because it is quite a bit off.

Comment: That is just Google's specs, not a master myself

Comment: Anyone have any advice here?? The DP is the same across all resources based on the equation dp = px / (dpi/160) so it should appear uniform across all screens yes?